# Why need to pass a callback accepting the previous state?

Tags: reactjs

```
class ClassCounterTwo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       count: 0
    }
  }

  incrementCount = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.incrementCount}>Count {this.state.count}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

When updating state based on previous state, why does React make **mistakes often** if you don't pass a callback accepting the previous state like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }
```

Sorry, just asking the question because I just saw somewhere the founder of Node.js said, "Try to push yourself to understand the system."

Comment: My advise is to use hooks instead of components so you dont have to worry about state. Read more here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @zee That's a strange comment. Hooks don't let you avoid worrying about state, they let you *do* state in the first place (in function components), and the useState hook has a callback version which will prompt the same question as the one Ridwan asked.

Comment: @NicholasTower Sure, hooks do have state (minus the overhead of the lifecycle of a component).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does React make mistakes often if you don't pass a callback accepting the previous state

When you set state, the component will rerender very soon, but not synchronously. This lets react batch up multiple changes and apply them all at once, so that only one render is needed when state is set multiple times in the same call stack.

So if you wrote two lines of code back to back like this:

```
this.setState({ count: 1 });
this.setState({ count: 2 });
```

It will only render once, with the 2 as the new state.

The problem comes if you write code that checks `this.state` with the assumption that `this.state` is up to date. For example:

```
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
```

If count was at 0 when this code began, then i will be telling react to set the count to 1, and then telling react to set it to **1 again**, since `this.state.count` didn't change in between these two lines. React will only render once, but since i told it 1 both times, that's what we'll be left with on the screen.

In most cases, these lines won't appear back to back in your code; they may be executing on different event listeners in different parts of your component, but in any event, the core point is that `this.state.count` only tells you what the count was when your code is executing, not what it is when we're just about to render.

So if you need to base your new state on the old one, there's the function version of setState. React will call the function and be sure to pass in the most recent value, letting you calculate the next state correctly no matter how many times you're updating it.